# What is the best option for setting up Task Scheduler hosted on windows azure using PAAS model

Tags: azure, powershell-4.0

I am trying to set up a Task Scheduler which will execute a Powershell script on monthly basis time period. The Powershell script has the logic to connect with the database and get data and put it into OpenXml based excel reports and send it to the expected users. All this setup is working fine in a VM. Now I need to move it to windows azure with PAAS model. On my analysis, I found that webjobs can serve the purpose of setting up a Task Scheduler.

I want to know is there any better option other than webjobs to set up the Task Scheduler.

Can anyone guide me to choose a better solution.

Comment: There are both 1st-party (Azure-specific) options and possible 3rd-party options. How you ultimately choose to schedule your tasks, or more specifically which is a "better option" is really a matter of opinion and specifically related to your app and what works best for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Azure Automation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/automation-schedules/) should be the solution in your case. You can set up the scheduled execution of PowerShell scripts with a lot of settings/etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution. I am able to implement it and test is successfully :).